# Do not install local modules via npm install when global available

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

How to configure package.json in such way that a dependency available globally will not be installed again locally?

For example, I have a project with jshint listed as dev-dependency; however, I already have jshint installed globaly and I want this module to use the global jshint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I ended up using `npx` for things that need to be installed globally, for example, `npx standard` in npm scripts. Works regardless global presence.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but in any case using global dependencies in the code is not a preferred way.

To get some information, type `npm help folders`, here's tl;dr part:

> - Local install (default): puts stuff in ./node_modules of the current package root.
> - Global install (with -g): puts stuff in /usr/local or wherever node is installed.
> - Install it locally if you're going to require() it.
> - Install it globally if you're going to run it on the command line.
> - If you need both, then install it in both places, or use npm link.

So, in your case, the last item, `link`, is the answer: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.

You need to run `npm link jshint` in your base folder. It'll link node_modules/jshint to the global one. This will create a symbolic link to the binary file, however, you can't use it in `require()` at some point of your code. As explained above, global packages are to run on command line so they are binary files.